# GXT date field - show date after clearing

Tags: gwt, gxt

I hava and GXT form with a DateField. When I clear the form by invoking the clear() method on my form panel, my date field is cleared and stays empty. But I want the date field to display current date after clearing. How can I do this?

Comment: You do not want a empty DateField ever or you want the current Date only on clearing the form?

Comment: I have current date when field is displayed for the first time. User can change the date, modify it, but when he clicks clear button, which invokes clear() method on form, I want the datefield to display current date again. I tried extending DateField and overriding clear() method, where I tried setValue(new Date()) but didn't do the trick :/

Answer (score 1):

Derive a custom component from DateField and do this:

```
@Override
public void clear() {
    super.clear();
    setValue(new Date());
}
```